# generate_series for multiple record types in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables that I want to query: `pest_counts` and `pests` which look like:

```
CREATE TABLE pests(id,name)
AS VALUES
  (1,'Thrip'),
  (2,'Fungus Gnosts');

CREATE TABLE pest_counts(id,pest_id,date,count)
AS VALUES
  (1,1,'2015-01-01'::date,14),
  (2,2,'2015-01-02'::date,5);
```

I want to use postgres' `generate_series` to show the number of each type of pest that was found for the date series:

**expected results**

```
name         | date       | count
-------------+------------+-------
Thrip        | 2015-01-01 | 14
Thrip        | 2015-01-02 | 0
....
Fungus Gnats | 2015-01-01 | 0
Fungus Gnats | 2015-01-02 | 5
...
```

I know I'll need something like the following but I'm not exactly sure how to do the rest:

```
SELECT date FROM generate_series('2015-01-01'::date, '2015-12-31'::date, '1 day') date
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually solve such problems by setting up a table for all the possible data points (here the pests and dates).  This is easily achieved by a `CROSS JOIN`, see the `WITH` query below.

Then, as the finishing step, I just (outer) join the existing measurements, based on the pest ID and date - optionally giving a default for the missing values via `COALESCE()`.

So, the whole query is:

```
WITH data_points AS (
    SELECT id, name, i::date
    FROM pests
    CROSS JOIN generate_series('2015-01-01'::date, '2015-01-05', '1 day') t(i)
) 
SELECT d.name, d.i, COALESCE(p.cnt, 0) 
FROM data_points AS d 
LEFT JOIN pest_counts AS p 
    ON d.id = p.pest_id 
    AND d.i = p.count_date;
```

Check it at work on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/abdb4/1).

**Note:** when either the table(s) or the generated series are big, doing the `CROSS JOIN` inside a CTE might be a bad idea. (It has to materialize all the rows, regardless of there is data for a given day or not).  In this case one should do the same in the `FROM` clause, as a parenthesized sub-join instead of the current reference to `data_points`.  This way the planner has a better understanding about the rows affected and the possibilities for using indexes.  I use the CTE in the example because it looks cleaner for the sake of the example.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest next time that you use fiddle.com in order to have an online schema to play with.

generate_series function returns a set of timestamp, so you will need to cast it to date outside the function. This is necessary in the current query as the `timestamp` won't match the `date` in the `pest_counts` table.

```
sandbox=# \df generate_series
   Schema   |      Name       |         Result data type          |                        Argument data types                         |  Type  
(...)
 pg_catalog | generate_series | SETOF timestamp without time zone | timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, interval | normal
 pg_catalog | generate_series | SETOF timestamp with time zone    | timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone, interval       | normal
(6 rows)
```

I will suggest something like:

```
SELECT p.name, pc.date, pc.count 
FROM generate_series('2015-01-01'::date, '2015-12-31'::date, '1 day') days 
join pest_counts pc ON (days::date = pc.date) 
join pests p ON (p.id = pc.pest_id) ;
```