# generate_series for multiple record types in postgresql. Fill missing with last previous value

Tags: postgresql

my question is closely related to the following question asked in this thread [generate_series for multiple record types in postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123824/generate-series-for-multiple-record-types-in-postgresql). The only difference is, that instead of only inserting missing values, I want to fill the gaps with the last previous value. To illustrate it with the same example. I have two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE pests(id,name)
AS VALUES
  (1,'Thrip'),
  (2,'Fungus Gnosts');

CREATE TABLE pest_counts(id,pest_id,date,count)
AS VALUES
  (1,1,'2015-01-01'::date,14),
  (2,2,'2015-01-02'::date,5);
```

The desired output should be nearly identical. However, I want to fill missing values with previous values, if possible. So the second entry for Thrip should be 14, since a previous value exists and the first value of Fungus Gnats should be 0, since no previous value exists. Is it possible to do this using Postgres?

**expected results**

```
name         | date       | count
-------------+------------+-------
Thrip        | 2015-01-01 | 14
Thrip        | 2015-01-02 | **14** <- fill with existing previous value.
....
Fungus Gnats | 2015-01-01 | 0
Fungus Gnats | 2015-01-02 | 5
...
```

Comment: it helps if you provide the ddl too.

Answer (score 2):

Example data with two rows added:

```
insert into pest_counts(pest_id, date, count) values
    (1, '2015-01-03', 10),
    (2, '2015-01-04', 7);

select * from pest_counts;

 id | pest_id |    date    | count 
----+---------+------------+-------
  1 |       1 | 2015-01-01 |    14
  2 |       2 | 2015-01-02 |     5
  3 |       1 | 2015-01-03 |    10
  4 |       2 | 2015-01-04 |     7
(4 rows)
```

Use `count()` as a window function to generate groups. Each not null value starts a new group:

```
select name, day, count, count(count) over (partition by name order by day) as grp
from (
    select id, name, day::date
    from pests
    cross join generate_series('2015-01-01'::timestamp, '2015-01-04', '1 day') day
) d
left join pest_counts on d.id = pest_id and day = date;

     name     |    day     | count | grp 
--------------+------------+-------+-----
 fungus gnats | 2015-01-01 |       |   0
 fungus gnats | 2015-01-02 |     5 |   1
 fungus gnats | 2015-01-03 |       |   1
 fungus gnats | 2015-01-04 |     7 |   2
 thrip        | 2015-01-01 |    14 |   1
 thrip        | 2015-01-02 |       |   1
 thrip        | 2015-01-03 |    10 |   2
 thrip        | 2015-01-04 |       |   2
(8 rows)
```

Now you can use `sum()` as a window function over partitions by names and generated groups:

```
select name, day, coalesce(count, sum(count) over (partition by name, grp order by day), 0) as count
from (
    select name, day, count, count(count) over (partition by name order by day) as grp
    from (
        select id, name, day::date
        from pests
        cross join generate_series('2015-01-01'::timestamp, '2015-01-04', '1 day') day
    ) d
    left join pest_counts on d.id = pest_id and day = date
) s;

     name     |    day     | count 
--------------+------------+-------
 fungus gnats | 2015-01-01 |     0
 fungus gnats | 2015-01-02 |     5
 fungus gnats | 2015-01-03 |     5
 fungus gnats | 2015-01-04 |     7
 thrip        | 2015-01-01 |    14
 thrip        | 2015-01-02 |    14
 thrip        | 2015-01-03 |    10
 thrip        | 2015-01-04 |    10
(8 rows)
```

Comment: this isn't safe because of dst. =( need to use timestamp without time zone

Comment: @EvanCarrollQWERHJKL - What isn't safe? What is dst. =(?

Comment: daylight savings time. you may find this informative https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/175963/2639

Comment: Ok, thanks. You've found a really nasty corner case,

Comment: yea, just an interesting thing that I try to get right lest someone gets stung with Pg's date math on tz.